# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect not cropping properly

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an image which I want to cut in half, so that it is only the bottom half of the image. I've been trying to do this by cropping the image, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything, the image is the same size, no matter what crop I apply to it. Is there something that I'm doing wrong in my implementation? My code is below.

```
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grey_%@", imagePath];

greyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
int width = greyImage.size.width;
int height = greyImage.size.height;

CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height / 2);
CGImageRef ref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([greyImage CGImage], myRect);
cropGrey = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref scale:greyImage.scale orientation:greyImage.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(ref);

[self addCreatedImage:greyImage toSubview:badgeView atX:30 atY:30 atWidth:badgeViewWidth - 60 atHeight:(badgeViewWidth - 60) / 2 isRounded:NO];
```

Whether I use greyImage, or cropGrey the image shows up exactly the same. I'm not sure why this is, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!